# How to restrict values for a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to restrict available values for a field. So the value of the column must be from specified set of values. Is it possible using migration/models? Or I have to do it manually in my DB?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll use validations for this. There's [a whole Rails guide on the topic](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). The specific helper you're looking for in this case is [`:inclusion`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion), e.g.:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :relationship_status,
    :inclusion  => { :in => [ 'Single', 'Married', 'Divorced', 'Other' ],
    :message    => "%{value} is not a valid relationship status" }
end
```

**Edit Aug. 2015:** As of Rails 4.1, you can use the `enum` class method for this. It requires that your column be an integer type:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum relationship_status: [ :single, :married, :divorced, :other ]
end
```

It automatically defines some handy methods for you, too:

```
p = Person.new(relationship_status: :married)

p.married? # => true
p.single? # => false

p.single!
p.single? # => true
```

You can read the documentation for `enum` here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: Is it possible to set on migration level?

Comment: You could set up constraints on the database level--MySQL and PostgreSQL have a column type `ENUM`, for example, but SQLite and Oracle do not--but Rails does not support them directly. You can use unsupported column types like e.g. `t.column :col_name, 'CUSTOM SQL TYPE'`, but you'll end up doing a lot of custom handling of those values and you won't be able to run those migrations on a different RDBMS, which is why (among others) the documentation specifically warns against it.

Comment: Using enum requires an additional int column. Plus it gets painful sometimes when you are trying to do delegations or queries. But good stuff nonetheless.

Comment: Using `enum` takes a single integer column. With `enum` you use an integer column instead of a string column; it does not require an additional column.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the amount of confidence you need.  You could just add a validator to your model to restrict it to those values but then you wont be sure that existing data will match (and will cause subsequent saves to fail because of validation) and also that other changes could be made by other apps/raw sql that would get around it.

If you want absolute confidence, use the database.

Here's what you might want to use if you do it in the database (which is quite limited compared to what a rails validator could do: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Comment: Thanks, yes, I know about validation. And can I specify my restrictions in migration file?

Comment: You could create a migration that finds ones that don't match and update/delete them.  Be warned though - if you use your models in your migration, you might trip people up if their models are out of sync with what the migration expects.